# How to insert MutationObserver into jQuery code

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm relatively new to jQuery.

EDITED QUESTION:
So instead of using setInterval to keep running the code every 400ms, I was given a tip that MutationObserver would be a better solution. I've now read about it online, I understand HOW it works, but I'm not experienced enough to implement it into my code. Is anyone willing to help? It's way easier for me to see it in practice so I can do this myself next time.

Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    const numbersToCheck = ['207747', '207746', '207743', '207742', '207739', '207741', '207744', '215364', '215371', '215406', '215405', '215366', '215365', '239511', '239512', '239513'];
    $('.mini-product').each((index, mp) => {
      let productNumber = $(mp).find('.product-number').first().text().trim();
      if (numbersToCheck.includes(productNumber)) {
        $(mp).find('.checkout-spacing').each((csi, cs) => {
          $(cs).css('display', 'none');
        });
      }
    });
});
```

This is what I found and read about MutationObserver:
https://gabrieleromanato.name/jquery-detecting-new-elements-with-the-mutationobserver-object

Comment: From the look of your code it seems you're trying to check for the presence of a dynamically created element - is that right? If so, checking the DOM every 400ms is very far from the ideal way to do this. Use a MutationObserver instead.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Hey. Yes kind of. The code will run on a product listing page where when the user scrolls, more products appear on the page with no page refresh. That's why I want it to keep checking for the condition. Do you know how to use MutationObserver? And is that what I need to achieve what I need? As said, I'm not that experienced. Thank you

Comment: You can easily find documentation and examples regarding MutationObserver in 2 minutes of googling. If you then have any more doubts about it, edit your question with that implementation.

Comment: @eloyra So I googled and read an article about it. It seems okay, I understood the concept. But I am nowhere near being experienced enough to understand how to implement this in my code as I've just learned about this. Do you think you can show me? Question updated and I inserted the link to the article I've read. I also removed setInterval from my code.

Comment: @R.Srour I've posted an answer. I hope you find it useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Working example of how to implement a MutationObserver ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wdmorx5y/)):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  setTimeout(() => {
    $('#container').append("<div class='mini-product'>m4</div>");
  }, 1000);
  
  const numbersToCheck = ['207747', '207746', '207743', '207742', '207739', '207741', '207744', '215364', '215371', '215406', '215405', '215366', '215365', '239511', '239512', '239513'];
  
  // Initial swipe
  // This may not be needed as I'm pretty sure the observer will trigger initially for the elements that are already on the HTML
  $('.mini-product').each((index, mp) => {
      // Your logic
  });
    
  // Now we watch for new elements
  const observer = new MutationObserver(() => {
    if ($('.mini-product').length) {
      console.log('Change detected!!');
      // Repeat logic here for the new element
      // observer.disconnect(); for ending the observer, though in your case maybe you don't want that at all
    }
  });
  
  // Param 1 of observe() must be a Node - document is a valid Node, but not advisable, limit the watcher to as small a context as possible
  observer.observe(document.getElementById('container'), {
    childList: true,
    subtree: true
  });
  
});
```

In short what is happening here is that you declare a observer that is going to watch the context you pass as the first parameter to the `observe()` function and then trigger the callback function you passed in the declaration when changes occur.

Note that here when the observer is triggered I'm looking for ALL the "mini-product" elements. You need to filter the previous ones or use the parameter the MutationObserver provides for your callback function to check exactly what has changed.

So:

```
  const observer = new MutationObserver(changes => {
    if ($('.mini-product').length) {
      console.log('Change detected!!');
      console.log(changes);
      // Repeat logic here for the new element
      // observer.disconnect(); for ending the observer, though in your case maybe you don't want that at all
    }
```

Check the documentation for more details about this param and others.

Comment: I appreciate the help, but I can't seem to get it to work for my code :( It manages to hide the class on page load, but new elements won't hide. I changed 'container' to 'mini-product-list' which is the parent().parent() of each mini-product. What else do I do?

Comment: Note that you are getting the element by ID, not by class. If you provide a working example I can debug it, but as it is I can't help you more.

Comment: My code is currently working, but not with the mutation thing you provided. I don't know where to put my code in the code you sent. And yes, I tried with an ID as well, still didn't work. When I tried with the class I changed it to getElementsByClassName. No luck.

Comment: What I mean is if you provide me the current code you are trying to use (with the MutationObserver), I can debug it. With "working" I don't mean "working well", just "that I can try it", like a jsfiddle.

Comment: Oh, okay. Sorry lol. Here: https://jsfiddle.net/ramisrour/305e7pv9/4/

Comment: That works and gives no error. It also looks fine to me. Without some HTML I don't know if it's working or not, I don't know your structure.

Comment: There is no error. But it only does what it's supposed to, before the page adds more content. The new elements still have the class which is supposed to be hidden. I can enter some HTML in the fiddle

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ramisrour/305e7pv9/7/
The HTML is only for 1 product on the page. There are several of this inside a wrapper. Just call that wrapper ```#site-wrapper```. Or it's direct parent which is ```.mini-product-list```

Comment: @R.Srour You are calling observer.observe inside the callback function passed to the MutationObserver constructor. You need to call it from outside there. Like in my example. I have adapted your Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/1xtae7sy/2/

Comment: I just tried it. Still only works on the first loaded elements and not the ones being added later. I tried changing the ```const``` to ```var``` and it worked. Now, new elements appearing by SCROLLING, works, but if I change anything in the filtering of the products in the menu, it doesn't work. Do you think const has anything to do with this? I read some differences about this and I'm suspecting this is it...

Comment: Both ```let``` and ```var``` worked instead of ```const``` but none of them worked using the filter

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep checking for that condition you can just remove this part

```
if (yourCodeHasBeenExecuted === true) {
    window.clearInterval(timer);
}
```

this would have cleared the interval (stop checking) if a variable `yourCodeHasBeenExecuted` would be set to true